# ERROR W05: Current page does not contain field with name 'display'

Tags: php

I have a simple web page for some arithmetic expressions, but when I tried to write a test for this code it threw me an unexpected error. I have a field 'display' where the value of the expression should be displayed after the 'evaluate' button is clicked. I don't understand, why won't this test find the field 'display', when it's present in my code.

```
<?php

require_once 'functions.php';

$display = $_POST['display'] ?? '';
$cmd = $_POST['cmd'] ?? '';
$number = $_POST['number'] ?? '';

if ($cmd === 'insert') {
    $display .= $number;
} else if ($cmd === 'plus') {
    if (!($display[-1] === '+')) {
        $display .= '+';
    }
} else if ($cmd === 'minus') {
    if (!($display[-1] === '-')) {
        $display .= '-';
    }
} else if ($cmd === 'evaluate') {
    $display = evaluate($display);
}

?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post">
    Display: <input type="text"
                    readonly="readonly"
                    name="display" value="<?= $display ?>" />

    <br /><br />

    Number: <input type="text" name="number" />
    <button type="submit"
            name="cmd"
            id="insert"
            value="insert">Insert</button>
    <br />
    <button type="submit" name="cmd" value="plus">+</button>
    <button type="submit" name="cmd" value="minus">-</button>

    <br /><br />

    <button type="submit" name="cmd" value="evaluate">Evaluate</button>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my function file:

```
<?php

function evaluate($expression) : int {
    if (preg_match('/[^\d +-]/', $expression, $matches)) {
        throw new RuntimeException(
            'expression contains illegal character: ' . $matches[0]);
    }

    try {
        $result = '';

        eval(sprintf('$result = %s;', $expression));

        return intval($result);

    } catch (Error $ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException('bad expression: ' . $expression);
    }
}
```

And the test that throws this error is:

```
function _calculatesArithmeticExpressions() {
    navigateTo(BASE_URL . '/ex4/calc/');

    setTextFieldValue('number', '4');

    clickButton('cmd', 'insert');

    clickButton('cmd', 'plus');

    setTextFieldValue('number', '3');

    clickButton('cmd', 'insert');

    clickButton('cmd', 'evaluate');

    clickButton('cmd', 'minus');

    setTextFieldValue('number', '-2');

    clickButton('cmd', 'insert');

    clickButton('cmd', 'evaluate');

    assertThat(getFieldValue('display'), is('9'));
}
```

This code should give the value '9' in the display field but instead throws an error. Why is this test not finding the 'display' field?

Comment: What does `getFieldValue()` do?

Comment: @brombeer Returns the value in the field of the form with the appropriate name.

Comment: Isn't `display` value only set on postback?

Answer (score 0):

Put the following line in functions.php.

```
$expression = str_replace('--', '+',$expression);
```

functions.php:

```
<?php

function evaluate($expression) : int {
    if (preg_match('/[^\d +-]/', $expression, $matches)) {
        throw new RuntimeException(
            'expression contains illegal character: ' . $matches[0]);
    }

    $expression = str_replace('--', '+',$expression); // *** In case of '--' the calculation does not execute.

    try {
        $result = '';

        eval(sprintf('$result = %s;', $expression));

        return intval($result);

    } catch (Error $ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException('bad expression: ' . $expression);
    }
}
```

I hope it helps